# Accessing the elements of an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am working on a machine learning problem in which the input has the shape `(10, 1, 5, 4)` for `10` samples, each sample shape  `(1,5,4)`. Below I show more details:

```
X = np.random.randn(10, 1, 5, 4)
a = np.zeros(5, dtype=int)
b = np.ones(5, dtype=int)
y = np.hstack((a,b))

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
(10, 1, 5, 4)
(10,)
```

The value of each sample in `X` is an array representing four parameters, thus:

```
X[0]

array([[[ 0.41246417,  1.0105981 , -0.64404467, -0.53073642],
    [-0.81929058, -0.14408449, -0.80003834,  0.974497  ],
    [-0.56111328,  0.63726127,  1.56704848,  1.16701553],
    [-0.3643063 , -0.57204605, -0.36627686,  0.61098743],
    [-0.25378511, -0.14519147, -0.22557196,  0.87733856]]])
```

In the above, the first row `[ 0.41246417,  1.0105981,  -0.64404467, -0.53073642]` represents say `min_speed, avg_speed, min_vel, avg_vel` so also other rows in this manner.

But I want to create a new array which is a stack of `min_speed, avg_speed, min_vel, avg_vel` so that  `min_speed = [0.41246417, -0.81929058, -0.56111328, -0.3643063, -0.25378511]` (i.e. first column in each case), `avg_speed =[1.0105981 , -0.14408449,0.63726127, -0.57204605, -0.14519147]` (second column) like that.

How I do manipulate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
X.transpose((0, 1, 3, 2))
```

Comment: Serious, thank you so much. can you please explain the magic?

Comment: Of course. `transpose` method swap axes. At the beginning axes are (0, 1, 2, 3), so after `transpose((0, 1, 3, 2))`, last two axes are swaped. Here you have explenation in details https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html